# What are the LE (latch enable) and the CLK (serial Clock) pins on the TQM8M9077?

Tags: raspberry-pi, software-defined-radio

I'm new here, so bear with me. I'm working on a sdr board for a raspberry pi and I have selected the TQM8M9077 as my DVGA. While looking at its [datasheet](http://www.triquint.com/products/d/DOC-A-00000753) and I came upon a few questions. What are the LE and CLK pins on the IC?

Answer (score 1):

To quote the datasheet:

> The TQM8M9077 has a CMOS SPI input compatible serial interface. This
>   serial control interface converts the serial data input stream to
>   parallel output word. The input is 3-wire (CLK, LE and SERIN) SPI
>   input compatible. At power up, the serial control interface resets the
>   DSA to the minimum gain state. The 6-bit SERIN word is loaded into the
>   register on rising edge of the CLK, MSB first. When LE is high, CLK is
>   disabled.

Therefore CLK is the SPI clock input and LE is the SPI chip select (active low).

Comment: If I understand correctly, the IC cannot function without the CLK, so theoretically I could use the have the LE connected to my VCC with a switch in between. when the switch was on, the IC would not be able to function.

Comment: No. The amp will function, regardless of the state of LE or CLK. The SPI interface is only to set the gain in the amp. These pins have otherwise no affect on the amp. Please read up on SPI to use this.